# Why does litespeed show PHP source, instead of interpreting?

Tags: php, litespeed

I have this issue on my server. It happens sometimes when I refresh my webpages. It seems litespeed wont pass `file.php` to php compiler and instead of rendering HTML and interpreting PHP, I will see my PHP source code. It won't happen always, only 2 or 3 times in 50 tries.

My PHP version is `5.3.10` but I had the same problem with `5.2.17` too. My Litespeed version is `V5.5` on `CentOS 6 (x64)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of struggle finally i figured out that my `.htaccress` length was the problem. In other words if `.htaccess` file length exceed 17 of lines it will confuse Litespeed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that shouldn't happen on any webserver. This might be because of a glitch (if you are testing with the same page).

Try to reproduce it and submit a bug report if it persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insure you've configured litespeed to parse PHP mime-types with PHP rather than just write them to standard out.  You'd have the same issue on Apache if the mime-types weren't configured.  If it truly is random and can't be linked to specific areas, etc, then it is likely a bug.

To add a PHP handler, you'd just add something along the lines of...

```
addType application/x-httpd-php5 php
```

Make sure your PHP files are always named with the extension that you specified in the handler.